# Why does Firefox Home icon not go to my Home page in 14.04?

Tags: icons, home-directory

With 14.04, in Firefox after pressing the Home icon I get the Ubuntu page in the current tab and my home page in a new tab. With 13.10, pressing the Home icon took me directly to my home page. Is this a deliberate change, or a bug?

Comment: The home icon will still get you wherever it is set to go (in Preferences/General). It doesn't as a rule open up a new tab. EDIT: it **is** possible to set multiple home pages, as illustrated in @mchid's answer.

Comment: Of course I have set the Home Page to the address of my page, and Firefox to open that on startup. But it doesn't open my page, it shows the Ubuntu page. My page is opened in a new tab.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to turn off "ubuntu integration" go to settings, click addons, and select extensions and disable the **integration** and **modification** extensions like in this example:

[image]

go to your firefox settings, click preferences and change the homepage from there you can set it to "Mozilla Firefox Start Page" or select whatever you want.

[image]

Comment: I have selected MY homepage, and it opens that in a new tab, not the current tab like 13.10 used to do.

Comment: @JasonMamford I don't know about the new tab thing but I updated the answer to get the ubuntu page out of the config.

Comment: I tried disabling all the integration and modification extensions one at a time and they didn't fix the problem. Maybe I should log this as a bug. Thanks for the help.